# Https response time in ruby

Tags: ruby, https

I'm trying to get webservice response time using ruby. My code

```
require 'net/http'
require 'benchmark'
require 'uri'

puts time = Benchmark.realtime = {Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://webservice"))}
```

It works fine but when I'm trying to get response time of https based url I get an error

```
'connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify faule
```

Is any way to fix this?

Comment: Is this really related to `Benchmark.realtime`?

Answer (score 0):

You should make request with enabled ssl:

```
uri = URI('https://secure.example.com/some_path?query=string')

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
end
```